# gsutil times out on every command

Tags: javascript, command-line, google-cloud-platform, gsutil

I have set up a bucket within a project to store uploaded files. Trying to make sure I can write to bucket with a test node program that uploads file to the bucket which fails. Then I tried to copy a file to the bucket using gsutil and it retries until it times out. Upon further investigation every command using gsutil results in a time out error. There seems to be little information on this error on the internet.

I have removed and regenerated the .boto file with `gcloud init` This command works. I have also done a clean reinstall of the sdk twice and still have the issue. The ACL for the project and the bucket have me included. Below is the node program and the timeout error from `gsutil cp test.txt gs://mybucket`

```
const {Storage} = require('@google-cloud/storage');

// Creates a client
const storage = new Storage();

/**
 * TODO(developer): Uncomment the following lines before running the sample.
 */
const bucketName = 'mybucket';
const filename = 'test.txt';

// Uploads a local file to the bucket
storage.bucket(bucketName).upload(filename, {
  // Support for HTTP requests made with `Accept-Encoding: gzip`
  gzip: true,
  metadata: {
    // Enable long-lived HTTP caching headers
    // Use only if the contents of the file will never change
    // (If the contents will change, use cacheControl: 'no-cache')
    cacheControl: 'public, max-age=31536000',
  },
});

console.log(`${filename} uploaded to ${bucketName}.`);
```

Error from node program

```
(node:18471) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Anonymous caller does not have storage.objects.create access to medchainvault/test.txt.
    at Util.parseHttpRespBody (/home/russell/go/src/github.com/medchain/business-network/storage-server/node_modules/@google-cloud/common/build/src/util.js:172:38)
    at Util.handleResp (/home/russell/go/src/github.com/medchain/business-network/storage-server/node_modules/@google-cloud/common/build/src/util.js:116:117)
    at retryRequest (/home/russell/go/src/github.com/medchain/business-network/storage-server/node_modules/@google-cloud/common/build/src/util.js:403:22)
    at onResponse (/home/russell/go/src/github.com/medchain/business-network/storage-server/node_modules/@google-cloud/common/node_modules/retry-request/index.js:200:7)
    at /home/russell/go/src/github.com/medchain/business-network/storage-server/node_modules/teeny-request/build/src/index.js:158:17
    at <anonymous>
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:189:7)
(node:18471) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 3)
(node:18471) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Error from gsutil:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):    0.0 B/s                                   
  File "/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/platform/gsutil/gsutil", line 22, in <module>
    gsutil.RunMain()
  File "/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/platform/gsutil/gsutil.py", line 117, in RunMain
    sys.exit(gslib.__main__.main())
  File "/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/platform/gsutil/gslib/__main__.py", line 407, in main
    perf_trace_token=perf_trace_token, user_project=user_project)
  File "/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/platform/gsutil/gslib/__main__.py", line 590, in _RunNamedCommandAndHandleExceptions
    user_project=user_project)
  File "/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/platform/gsutil/gslib/command_runner.py", line 372, in RunNamedCommand
    return_code = command_inst.RunCommand()
  File "/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/platform/gsutil/gslib/commands/cp.py", line 1184, in RunCommand
    seek_ahead_iterator=seek_ahead_iterator)
  File "/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/platform/gsutil/gslib/command.py", line 1420, in Apply
    arg_checker, should_return_results, fail_on_error)
  File "/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/platform/gsutil/gslib/command.py", line 1491, in _SequentialApply
    worker_thread.PerformTask(task, self)
  File "/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/platform/gsutil/gslib/command.py", line 2157, in PerformTask
    results = task.func(cls, task.args, thread_state=self.thread_gsutil_api)
  File "/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/platform/gsutil/gslib/commands/cp.py", line 795, in _CopyFuncWrapper
    preserve_posix=cls.preserve_posix_attrs)
  File "/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/platform/gsutil/gslib/commands/cp.py", line 992, in CopyFunc
    gzip_exts=self.gzip_exts, preserve_posix=preserve_posix))
  File "/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/platform/gsutil/gslib/utils/copy_helper.py", line 3520, in PerformCopy
    allow_splitting=allow_splitting, gzip_encoded=gzip_encoded)
  File "/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/platform/gsutil/gslib/utils/copy_helper.py", line 2026, in _UploadFileToObject
    parallel_composite_upload, logger)
  File "/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/platform/gsutil/gslib/utils/copy_helper.py", line 1877, in _DelegateUploadFileToObject
    elapsed_time, uploaded_object = upload_delegate()
  File "/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/platform/gsutil/gslib/utils/copy_helper.py", line 2009, in CallNonResumableUpload
    gzip_encoded=gzip_encoded_file)
  File "/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/platform/gsutil/gslib/utils/copy_helper.py", line 1588, in _UploadFileToObjectNonResumable
    fields=UPLOAD_RETURN_FIELDS, gzip_encoded=gzip_encoded)
  File "/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/platform/gsutil/gslib/cloud_api_delegator.py", line 292, in UploadObject
    gzip_encoded=gzip_encoded)
  File "/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/platform/gsutil/gslib/gcs_json_api.py", line 1385, in UploadObject
    gzip_encoded=gzip_encoded)
  File "/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/platform/gsutil/gslib/gcs_json_api.py", line 1229, in _UploadObject
    global_params=global_params)
  File "/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/platform/gsutil/gslib/third_party/storage_apitools/storage_v1_client.py", line 1197, in Insert
    download=download)
  File "/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/platform/gsutil/third_party/apitools/apitools/base/py/base_api.py", line 729, in _RunMethod
    http, http_request, **opts)
  File "/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/platform/gsutil/third_party/apitools/apitools/base/py/http_wrapper.py", line 346, in MakeRequest
    check_response_func=check_response_func)
  File "/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/platform/gsutil/third_party/apitools/apitools/base/py/http_wrapper.py", line 396, in _MakeRequestNoRetry
    redirections=redirections, connection_type=connection_type)
  File "/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/platform/gsutil/gslib/gcs_json_media.py", line 276, in NewRequest
    connection_type=override_connection_type)
  File "/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/platform/gsutil/third_party/oauth2client/oauth2client/transport.py", line 159, in new_request
    credentials._refresh(orig_request_method)
  File "/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/platform/gsutil/third_party/oauth2client/oauth2client/client.py", line 761, in _refresh
    self._do_refresh_request(http)
  File "/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/platform/gsutil/third_party/google-reauth-python/google_reauth/reauth_creds.py", line 120, in _do_refresh_request
    headers=headers))
  File "/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/platform/gsutil/third_party/google-reauth-python/google_reauth/reauth.py", line 269, in refresh_access_token
    headers=headers)
  File "/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/platform/gsutil/third_party/google-reauth-python/google_reauth/_reauth_client.py", line 151, in refresh_grant
    headers=headers)
  File "/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/platform/gsutil/third_party/google-reauth-python/google_reauth/reauth_creds.py", line 107, in http_request
    body=body, headers=headers)
  File "/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/platform/gsutil/third_party/oauth2client/oauth2client/transport.py", line 282, in request
    connection_type=connection_type)
  File "/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/platform/gsutil/third_party/httplib2/python2/httplib2/__init__.py", line 1694, in request
    (response, content) = self._request(conn, authority, uri, request_uri, method, body, headers, redirections, cachekey)
  File "/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/platform/gsutil/third_party/httplib2/python2/httplib2/__init__.py", line 1434, in _request
    (response, content) = self._conn_request(conn, request_uri, method, body, headers)
  File "/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/platform/gsutil/gslib/gcs_json_media.py", line 529, in _conn_request
    conn.connect()
  File "/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/platform/gsutil/third_party/httplib2/python2/httplib2/__init__.py", line 1100, in connect
    sock.connect(sockaddr)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 228, in meth
    return getattr(self._sock,name)(*args)
socket.timeout: timed out
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am assuming that this is a node.js project running as a server and not code bundled to run in a browser.

Your problem is defined in this line:

```
Error: Anonymous caller does not have storage.objects.create access to medchainvault/test.txt.
```

This error means that your code is not using credentials.

Normally, this line of your code will select one of your credentials using ADC:

```
const storage = new Storage();
```

However, none are found.

You have several options:

1. Run `gcloud auth login` to setup credentials.
2. Create a service account, download the Json file and use those credentials (recommended) when creating your client.

Use code similar to this:

```
const storage = new Storage({
  projectId: 'project-id',
  keyFilename: '/path/to/keyfile.json'
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the good response- I have run `gcloud auth login` numerous times successfully and still get the error from the node program and gsutils. However, I did just run `gcloud auth login` and received a warning about ADC 

```  
WARNING: `gcloud auth login` no longer writes application default credentials.
If you need to use ADC, see:
  gcloud auth application-default --help

Comment: The recommended approach is to use a service account. Skip using User Credentials and do it correctly from the start.